# To overcome image loading issues in ionic 3 iframe and inapp browser of ionic 3

Tags: image, iframe, ionic3, inappbrowser

```
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="upgrade-insecure-requests">
```

For ionic 3, put this inside  header part of index.html (www/index.html  )...It works...

Comment: Is this a question or are you answering yourself?

Comment: this is a solution.. for someone it helps